Replacing Class Background Color based on inner text
Just can't figure out why this code won't work.
I'm trying to replace the background colour of a class based on the inner text of the document.
I don't have an Id to connect to so I have to search for class.
    <script> 
if (window.location.href.startsWith('https://mytestsite.com.au/')) {
if (( document.documentElement.innerText).indexOf('API') > -1) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('training-card__name').style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
}
</script>

Help appreciated.

getElementsByClassName() returns a HTMLCollection. That doesn't have a style property.
You'll need to iterate over the collection and add the style to each element separately.

document.getElementsByClassName() method returns a collection of elements with a specified class name. then you need iterate over that collection to specify the background color.
Refer the code below:


if (window.location.href.startsWith('https')) { // Replace with your url - https://mytestsite.com.au/
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('training-card__name');
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].innerText.indexOf('API') > -1) { // Check if a inner text contains API in specific element
      elements[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
  }
} else {
  console.log("This script only runs on https://mytestsite.com.au/");
}
.training-card__name {
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #000;
    }
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Test Site</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="training-card__name">Basic Training</div>
  <div class="training-card__name">API Training</div>
  <div class="training-card__name">Advanced API Training</div>
  <div class="training-card__name">Intermediate Training</div>
</body>

</html>



